# TableAdapter unpredictably stops writing to DB

Tags: c#, tableadapter

I am at a complete loss to explain it.

Using a .Net XSD as a data set.
The TableAdapter has been extended in DataSet.cs to accept a token used to set the connection string, based on the VS build options.
Using a BackGroundworker to perform writes on a separate thread.

The application will collect data into a queue in memory using a custom type. After data collection the elements of the queue are loaded into a datatable and, when the queue is empty, the table is updated to the back end. This is usually done while the user is preparing for another data collection session. Performance is good with thousands of rows updated in a few seconds. The application connects to a local instance of MSSQL Express to write. This issue has occurred both writing locally and remotely.

This works well for the implementation except for an unpredictable failure to write data. The failure can happen after 50, 500, 5000, or 50000 elements are processed and does not seem to have any identifiable preconditions. In every case the writecount will register a few calls to WriteToDB() and then stop updating. None of the data in the queue actually gets written to the DB because the ta.Update(dt); line is never called. This leads me to believe the thread is being stopped, but testing shows that it continues to execute and just doesn't do anything. Not sure if the problem is the Thread, the TableAdapter, or the DataTable but something is getting out of order and stopping the write.

Zero is passed to the ReportProgress method so that it can interact with the GUI and update display elements as needed.
I've examined the memory usage using the debugger and this is not coming anywhere near the machine's available memory.
I introduced (and later removed) ManualResetEvent to try to manage the thread to prevent this but it did not resolve the issue.

Has anyone experienced any similar behavior?
Can someone provide any insight to resolving this?

Sample code:

```
private TableAdapterNamespace.TableAdapter ta = null;
private Namespace.DataTable dt = null;
private Queue<CustomClass> Q = null;

public Constructor()
{
...
    ta = new TableAdapterNamespace.TableAdapter(prgMain.DB_CONNECT);
    dt = new Namespace.DataTable();
    Q = new Queue<CustomClass>(100000);
...
}

private void DBWriter_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
...
    if (Q.Count > 0)
    {
        WriteToDB(Q.Dequeue(), strsource);
        writecount += 1;
        BGWWriter.ReportProgress(0);
    }
    else
    {
        dt.EndLoadData();
        ta.Update(dt);
        BGWWriter.ReportProgress(0);
    }
...
}


private void WriteToDB(CustomClass bt, string strsource)
{
    dt.DataRow drn = DataTable.NewDataRow();
...
     drn.User = Environment.UserName;
     drn.ID = ID;
     drn.SessionStamp = bt.Stamp;
     dt.LoadDataRow(drn.ItemArray, System.Data.LoadOption.Upsert);
...
}
```

Intrusive thought:  Could this be caused by the Queue being filled and emptied repeatedly?

Comment: If you attach a debugger to your program and break execution, what is the application doing?  Is it stopped on a `lock` statement or when invoking back to the UI thread?  If so, that sounds like a client side deadlock.  Is it stopped when executing the database call?  If so, the database could be blocking because of a concurrency issue.

Comment: @Paul Williams - I'll take a look, but it's difficult to pin down.

Comment: If you cannot attach a debugger-- say, if it was production code-- I would recommend capturing a memory dump using Windows Task Manager or Process Explorer and then use DebugDiag to analyze the dump file.  DebugDiag has some nice error and warning messages that can sometimes highlight exactly what the problem is.